# Javascript object returns full code instead of result

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've written the following chrome extension to detect and what URL a user is on and process some data from a specific URL. Background.js contains the following code:

```
var triggerURL = "http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/";

function SearchURL(theURL) {
  this.URL = theURL;
  this.checkURLorigin = function() {
    if (this.URL.indexOf(triggerURL) !== -1) {
      console.log("you're on the search page");
      return true;
    }
    else
      return false;
  };
  this.query = function() {
    console.log(this.URL);
    var index = this.URL.indexOf("q=");
    var searchQuery = this.URL.substr(index + 2);
    return searchQuery;
  };
}

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function(details){
  var currentSearchURL = new SearchURL(details.url);
  console.log(currentSearchURL.checkURLorigin);
  if (currentSearchURL.checkURLorigin) {
    msg = currentSearchURL.query;
    console.log("you're on the search page, query = " + msg);
  }
},
{urls: [triggerURL + "*"], types: ["main_frame"]}, ["blocking"]);
```

console.log shows however that the code in the SearchURL object is not executed, instead the function's content are printed in the console. Why is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a (). The correct call should be

```
 msg = currentSearchURL.query();
```